# Launch Screen storyboard migration issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, launch, launch-screen

I have an app built in Objective C which uses **Launch Screen Image Set** as a splash screen.
According to recent Apple's new Guidelines

> Apps for iPhone or iPad must be built with the iOS 13 SDK or later and
> use an Xcode storyboard to provide the app’s launch screen.
> Reference - https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=03262020b

I removed the Launch image and added a LaunchScreen.storyboard with an UIImageView. After making the mentioned change all my screens following the Launch screen appear to have scaled-down in dimensions whereas before adding the LaunchScreen.storyboard it worked fine for all iPad screen sizes.

This is how the screen following the launch screen looks when the Launch Image Set is used[image]

This is how the screen following the launch screen looks when LaunchScreen.storybpard is used[.  [image]

I am confused as to why migrating from Launch screen image to LaunchScreen.storyboard is affecting the constraints of all the remaining screens. Please could someone help me here?

PS: Both screenshots are of iPad Pro 12.9 inch

Comment: Because without a launch storyboard (and presumably iPad Pro launch images) iOS scales your app so that it is running at iPad resolution rather than the full iPad Pro resolution.  With a launch storyboard you must now set appropriate constraints so that your user interface adapts to the screen size.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks, but I already have the constraints it worked fine before the storyboard, not sure if I got you correctly here

Comment: What constraints do you have? Do you have specific width/height constraints?  That is what it looks like.

Comment: @Paulw11 Yup I do have specific height/width constraints, maybe that could be the issue

Comment: I'm having similar issue. In my case, after switching to LaunchScreen, font looks smaller.